# Python / google Spreadsheet - How to remove [' '] or get all columns except the first one

Tags: python, google-sheets, discord

As so many others, I'm new to python and just playing around a little, to build a discord bot for my wow guild.

So far, I've acces to my google spreadsheet and are reading the values with `heals = worksheet.col_values(2)`

This works fine. My output is in a discord embed and looks like this `embed.add_field(name="Healer", value=format(sep.join(heals)), inline=True)`

But this method includes ofcourse every value from the column. Now I want to exclude the first row. (A1, B1, C1, and so on)

I have approached different ways and am using now `test = worksheet.get('A2:A')`, this works to a certain degree. It does what I want, and starts with A2 BUT I can't get it to be formatted in my discord output.

I'm doing my output with `embed.add_field(name="Tanks", value=format('\n'.join(map(str, test))), inline=True)`

It looks like this:

```
['Tim']
['Julian']
```

So my question is, how do I get rid of the brackets OR other methods, how I can exclude the first row.
I hope I could explain it in a understandable way.

[my discord output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qQPM.png)

Comment: Can you share with us the print of test: `print(test)`

Comment: The print of test is   `[['Tim'], ['Julian']]`

Comment: can you try this: `test = [item for sublist in test for item in sublist]` . Put that after you define the `test` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `test` has the following structure:

```
test = [['Tim'], ['Julian']]
```

Put this after the definition of `test`:

```
test = [item for sublist in test for item in sublist]
'\n'.join(map(str,test))
```

and this will give this output:

```
'Tim\nJulian'
```

which you can pass as a value to `add_field()`.

### More explanation:

In more detail, `test = [['Tim'], ['Julian']]` is **a list of lists**. In order to **flatten** this list and get a **list of elements** instead, you can use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Please have a look at the documentation to see how the latter work.

Comment: I've just tried it in a hurry, and it looks like it works. I will try in later more in detail. Thank you very much!

Could you maybe be so kind and explain, what your solution exactly does?

Comment: @harlekiNN I added a little bit of explanation. I redirect you to this link to read more about comprehensions lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html